# SQL aggregate query repeating primary key column

Tags: sql

I am querying two database tables, `Invoice` and `Payments`. I want to get the sum of all payments for a particular invoice, however the results 'repeat' the invoice numbers instead of aggregating the values.

The tables are

**Invoices**

```
invoiceID
dueDate
invoiceAmount
```

**Payments**

```
paymentID
invoiceID
fine
amount
```

This is my query :

```
SELECT 
    Invoices.invoiceID, invoiceAmount, 
    COALESCE((SUM (fine + amount)), 0) AS 'Total'  
FROM 
    Payments, Invoices 
WHERE 
    Payments.invoiceID = Invoices.invoiceID
GROUP BY  
    Invoices.invoiceID, dueDate, datePaid, invoiceAmount
ORDER BY 
    Invoices.invoiceID
```

The results of this are something like

```
invoiceID invoiceAmount Total
---------------------------------
   2        270000      170000
   2        270000      100000
  67        400000      150000
  67        400000      250000
```

I expect the output to be

```
invoiceID    invoiceAmount  Total 
----------------------------------
   2           270000       270000
  67           400000       400000
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Also: what **concrete RDBMS** is this for?? SQL is just the "generic" language - not a database system - and each system has its own ways of doing things - please add a relevant task for `oracle`,  `sql-server`, `mysql`, `postgresql` or whatever else you might be using ....

Comment: You need to remvoe `dueDate` and `datePaid` from your `GROUP BY` clause

Answer (score 0):

use join and remove dueDate, datePaid from group by

```
SELECT 
    Invoices.invoiceID, invoiceAmount, 
    COALESCE((SUM (fine + amount)), 0) AS 'Total'  
FROM 
    Payments join Invoices 
on 
    Payments.invoiceID = Invoices.invoiceID
GROUP BY  
    Invoices.invoiceID,invoiceAmount
ORDER BY 
    Invoices.invoiceID
```

Comment: Thanks, It Worked, the extra fields in the join made it "repeat" the primary key value

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you really want a `left join` to capture invoices that have no payments:

```
SELECT i.invoiceID, i.invoiceAmount, 
       SUM(COALESCE(fine, 0) + COALESCE(amount, 0)) as Total
FROM Invoices i LEFT JOIN
     Payments p  
     ON p.invoiceID = i.invoiceID
GROUP BY i.invoiceID, i.invoiceAmount
ORDER BY i.invoiceID;
```

Note that `COALESCE()` is used on each column.  If one of the values is `NULL`, then this probably does what you intend.